# Swift UI Navigation Issue

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

So I have a tabview and a search with a NavigationView.  If you click on a user you go to profile page and the profile page has a scrollview with grid where you can click and go to post details. If I remove the NavigationView from profileView it goes to post details but then back to profile.  If I add the NavigationView it stays on the post details but then there are two navigation bars.

SearchView:

```
    // MARK: - LIST OF USERS
// LIST DIDN'T WORK, HAD TO USE SCROLLVIEW
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(userListVM.users.filter { searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.fullname.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)}, id: \.id) { user in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: UserProfileView(userVM: UserViewModel(user: user)),
                label: {
                    SearchUserCellView(user: user)
                }
            )
        }
    } // END:LAZYVSTACK
} // END:SCROLLVIEW
```

ProfileView:

```
ScrollView {
     UserProfileGridView(userVM: userVM)
} // END:SCROLLVIEW
```

GridView:

```
// MARK: - BODY
var body: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: items, spacing: 2, content: {
        ForEach(postListVM.posts.filter {$0.ownerUid == userVM.user.uid}, id: \.id) { post in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: CommentView(postVM: PostViewModel(post: post)),
                label: {
                    if post.postImgUrl.isEmpty {
                        Image("dogs")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: width, height: width)
                            .clipped()
                    } else {
                        KFImage(URL(string: post.postImgUrl))
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: width, height: width)
                            .clipped()
                    }
                })
        } // END:FOREACH
    }) // END:LAZYVGRID
}
```

Comment: It is not clear expected behaviour, please elaborate more and provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Navigation User List | click on User and go to profile page.  On Profile page there is a GridView with navigation Links to Post page.  Here is the problem, I want them to click on one of the posted images in a GridView and stay on the Post page.  Unfortunately it flashes to Post page and then goes right back to profile page if I don't have a navigationView on profile page.  If I do it stays like I want it to, but there are then two navigation bars.